# Skip first line in import statement using gc.open_by_url from gspread (i.e. add header=0)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import, gspread

What is the equivalent of `header=0` in `pandas`, which recognises the first line as a heading in `gspread`?

**pandas import statement (correct)**

```
import pandas as pd

# gcp / google sheets URL
df_URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wKtvNfWSjPNC1fNmTfUHm7sXiaPyOZMchjzQBt1y_f8/edit?usp=sharing"

raw_dataset = pd.read_csv(df_URL, na_values='?',sep=';'
                          , skipinitialspace=True, header=0, index_col=None)
```

Using the gspread function, so far I import the data, change the first line to the heading then delete the first line after but this recognises everything in the DataFrame as a string. I would like to recognise the  first line as a heading right away in the import statement.

**gspread import statement that needs header=True equivalent**

```
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


# gcp / google sheets url
df_URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wKtvNfWSjPNC1fNmTfUHm7sXiaPyOZMchjzQBt1y_f8/edit?usp=sharing"

# importing the data from Google Drive  setup
gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

# read data and put it in dataframe
g_sheets = gc.open_by_url(df_URL) 

df = pd.DataFrame(g_sheets.get_worksheet(0).get_all_values())

  
# change first row to header
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]) 

# drop first row
df.drop(index=df.index[0], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: what `import` statement are you referring to?

Comment: Hi @JasonGoal the one after "when using the gspread function as"

Comment: `.get_all_values()` → `.get_all_records()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [API documentation](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.get_all_records), you probably want to use:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(g_sheets.get_worksheet(0).get_all_records(head=1))
```

The `.get_all_records` method returns a dictionary of with the column headers as the keys and a list of column values as the dictionary values.  The argument `head=<int>` determines which row to use as keys; rows start from 1 and follow the numeration of the spreadsheet.

Since the values returned by `.get_all_records()` are lists of strings, the data frame constructor, `pd.DataFrame`, will return a data frame that is all strings.  To convert it to floats, we need to replace the empty strings, and the the dash-only strings (`'-'`) with NA-type values, then convert  to `float`.

Luckily pandas DataFrame has a convenient method for replacing values `.replace`.  We can pass it mapping from the string we want as NAs to None, which gets converted to NaN.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = g_sheets.get_worksheet(0).get_all_records(head=1)

na_strings_map= {
    '-': None, 
    '': None
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).replace(na_strings_map).astype(float)
```